# How to read, copy and show items from azure mobile tables in UWP C#

Tags: c#, azure, mobile, uwp

Using Azure Mobile Services I can add items to a Azure Table with this code:

```
    private async void Aggi_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Bestemmye oggetto = new Bestemmye
        {
            Text = RicBest.Text  //a textbox
        };

        await App.MobileService.GetTable<Bestemmye>().InsertAsync(oggetto);

    }
```

How can I read table items? How can I save them into a listbox?

Comment: @CSharpRocks i tried nothing, this is the first time i use azure... i found this in the quickstart option in azure and it works. But to read table items i found nothing similar to this code

Answer (score 0):

So I know this is totally other then what you use now. But I had a lot of problems getting everything to work too. This is what I use now.

To insert data

```
IMobileServiceTable<Test> TestObj = App.MobileService.GetTable<Test>();

try
{
    Test obj = new Test();
    obj.test = test.Text;
    obj.test1 = test1.Text;
    obj.test2 = test2.Text;
    obj.test3 = test3.Text;

    TestObj.InsertAsync(obj);
    MessageDialog msgDialog = new MessageDialog("Data Inserted!!!");
    msgDialog.ShowAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
        MessageDialog msgDialogError = new MessageDialog("Error : " + ex.ToString());    msgDialogError.ShowAsync();
}
```

To read first create a new .cs file Test.cs
The property names are the ones you use in the database

```
public class Test 
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string test { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Name")]
    public string test1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Title")]
    public string test2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Description")]
    public string test3 { get; set; }

}
```

The code executed to read:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IMobileServiceTable<Test> productTest = App.MobileService.GetTable<Test>();
    // This query filters out.
    MobileServiceCollection<Test, Test> products = await productTest
        .Where(Test => Test.test == "Test")
        .ToCollectionAsync();

    lb.ItemsSource = products;

}
```

Now the XAML listbox

```
<ListBox 
    x:Name="lb">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="152">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding test}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding test1}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding test2}"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Took me like 50 hours to find this out but it works for me.